# CSS: change header height while hovering on other element

Tags: css, header, hover, height, element

I am trying to change the height of the header while I'm hovering over a div in the header. The div is a dropdown button and the header is supposed to extend a specific amount of pixels to fit the drop down-content.

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <nav class="menyer">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                 </div>
         </div>
     </nav>
 </header>
```

You can find all source code [here](http://jsbin.com/tuxovikuto/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: try to remove height from  .menyer class.. i think that's what you need.. right?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/tex75gop/

Comment: @Leothelion - more Like this - https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/tex75gop/1/

Comment: Or possibly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545947/position-absolute-and-parent-height

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/ga7a3mm2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the height of an element while hovering over a child-element. All you can do is to expand the height of the inner element so that the outer element stretches accordingly. That only works if there is no fixed height on the base-element (your header)

basic example:

```
<header> <ul> <li>Item 1</li> <li> Item 2 </li> </ul> </header>
```

CSS:

```
li{display:block;height: 30px;}
li:hover{height: 50px;}
header{background-color:red}
```

That way the header extends if you hover over a li element. If you need a minimum height for your header to work (because of the design, ... ) then set a min-height for the header.

Comment: So.. is there any other option? You could paste the code that should work for OP.

Comment: It would really depend on what he would want to do exactly. srry edit coming up

Comment: _I am trying to change the height of the header while I'm hovering over a div in the header_

Comment: Sorry, posted my reply too fast, still new to this site. I know what he said in the post (and edited my post for a suggestion), to add to the solution in the duplicate link.