# div does not resize to height if child is positioned absolutly

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a DIV.
I want to "overhang" the image outside the DIV a little, so I've positioned it absolute and the parent container as relative. When I do that, the parent DIV no longer resizes its height to contain the image. 
How can I do this?

the HTML

```
      <div class=".twelve.columns" id="header">
        <div id="logoWrapper">
                <img src="https://nbson.com/sni/images/logo.png" class="ssImg">
                <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>      
      </div>
```

the CSS

```
.ssImg{
    width:100%;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
}
#header{
     margin-top:0;
     background:#000;    
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     border:1pt solid pink; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwur8bdn/)

Comment: If you want to put two classes on an element use like `<div class="twelve columns">`, not like `<div class=".twelve.columns">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Absolutely positioned elements are completely removed from the document flow, and thus their dimensions cannot alter the dimensions of their parents.
>   If you really had to achieve this affect while keeping the children as position: absolute, you could do so with JavaScript [[...]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13546011/3162554)

To get the effect described without javascript, you could use negative values for bottom or top. I also updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwur8bdn/2/) for your concrete example.

```css
.ssImg{
 width:100%;
}
.clr{
 clear:both;
}
#header{
  margin-top:0;
  background:#000;  
  position:relative;a
  width:100%;
  border:1pt solid pink; 
}

#logoWrapper{
 width:15%;
 min-width:120px;
 margin-left:10px;
 position:relative; /* this is new */
        bottom: -40px; /* this is new */
}
```

```html
<div class="twelve columns" id="header">
    <div id="logoWrapper">
            <img src="https://nbson.com/sni/images/logo.png" class="ssImg">
            <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```css
html, body {   
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.ssImg{
   width: 100%;
}

#header{
  background-color: #000;  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set the height what you want */
  border: 1pt solid pink; 
}

#logoWrapper{
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logoWrapper">
    <img src="https://nbson.com/sni/images/logo.png" class="ssImg">
  </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

If you want to put two classes on an element use like `<div class="twelve columns">`, not like `<div class=".twelve.columns">`

Secondly, regarding your question:

Absolutely positioned elements are *removed from the flow* and thus, no longer taken into consideration when it comes to calculating dimensions for the parent element.

You can solve it by explicitly setting the `height` and `width` you need on the element.