# Auto resize div to fit two (or more) stacked pictures in it

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `display: inline-block` that has two or more IMGs in it. IMGs are "stacked" on top of each other (I also have script that sets z-index when necessary), so I use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` for these IMGs. I need to resize containing div to fit the biggest image in it. The problem is, that images are loaded dynamically and have different sizes and I need to resize containing div to fit the biggest one currently in it. When I don not use no `position: absolute`, containing div resizes automatically to fit the image, but in that case I cannot place images on top of each other.
So, is it possible to achieve this with css only? The goal is to have several images with unknown sizes stacked on top of each other.
Thank you.

(snippet is for illustration only)

```js
window.onload=function()
{
  let lastPic=1;
  
  setInterval(function()
  {
    let pics=document.querySelectorAll(".pic");
    pics[lastPic].style.zIndex="";
    lastPic=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
    pics[lastPic].style.zIndex="3";
  }, 1000);
  
};
```

```css
div#container
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  padding: .5em;
}

img.pic
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

div#container img:nth-child(1)
{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
div#container img:nth-child(2)
{
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);

}
div#container img:nth-child(3)
{
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  background: rgba(0, 255,0,.5);
}
div#container img:nth-child(4)
{
  border: 1px solid #0ff;
  background: rgba(0,255,255,.5);

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>

<div id="container">
<img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/1.png">
<img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/2.png">
<img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/3.png">
<img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/4.png">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure Cris, that's why I'm asking the question

Comment: Just create a css grid container  with one column and one row, and place all images inside specifying `grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-start: 1;` for each image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position: absolute and parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545947/position-absolute-and-parent-height)

Comment: @ChrisLi not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `position:absolute`, use `display:grid` **(in this case `display:inline-grid` so it shrink wraps the images)** and put all the images in the same row & column.

> Note: older versions of Internet Explorer either do not support CSS-Grid *or* support an older version of the specification and will require specific `-ms- grid` properties.

```css
div#container {
  display: inline-grid;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

img.pic {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: block;
}

div#container img:nth-child(1) {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div#container img:nth-child(2) {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

div#container img:nth-child(3) {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

div#container img:nth-child(4) {
  border: 1px solid #0ff;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/1.png">
  <img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/2.png">
  <img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/3.png">
  <img class="pic" src="https://dom.etogo.net/picsrotate/test/4.png">
</div>
```

Comment: So fast. I just wrote that as a comment while you already have it as an answer.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning (and adding) the rules needed for IE10+.

Comment: Also your introductory text recommends to use `display: grid;` while your actual code uses `display: inline-grid;`.

Comment: Exactly what I need, ty!