# Have child of td element take up full width and height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `<td>` element with a little bit of padding, and I'd like to shade in the entire table cell when it's immediate child is a `<mark>` element.

I'm using markdown to generate the table itself, so simply adding a class like `<td class="highlight">` isn't really an option.

#### Basic Table Setup

Here's a basic table setup

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ranger</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><mark>Frida <br/> Kahtlo</mark></td>
      <td><mark>Cat</mark></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With some basic CSS

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
```

#### Attempt #1

One idea was to absolutely position the `<mark>` element and pin it to all four sides:

```css
td > mark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem possible to [set the parent parent height from an absolutely positioned child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13545947/1366033), so the contents overflows the `<td>`

[image: example one]

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

td > mark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ranger</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><mark>Frida <br/> Kahtlo</mark></td>
      <td><mark>Cat</mark></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Attempt #2

Another idea was to reverse the padding with a negative margin like this:

```css
td > mark {
    display: block;
    margin: -8px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

However, if there is a line wrap in another cell, I can't get the child element to occupy the full height available

[image: example two]

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

td > mark {
    display: block;
    margin: -8px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ranger</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><mark>Frida <br/> Kahtlo</mark></td>
      <td><mark>Cat</mark></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Q: Any other ways that this might be possible?*

Comment: Do you want to add a background in the specific "Frida Kahtlo" row?

Comment: @MultaniSadik, yes, in this case.  But in the general case applying the style at the cell level.  If only one `<td>` has a direct child of `<mark>`, that would be the only one that needed highlighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a big `box-shadow` and hide the overflow

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}
td {
 overflow:hidden;
}
td > mark {
  display:inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px yellow; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ranger</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><mark>Frida <br/> Kahtlo</mark></td>
      <td><mark>Cat</mark></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to loop all marks and add bg color yellow to their parent :

```
document.querySelectorAll('mark').forEach(function(item){
  item.parentElement.style.backgroundColor ="ff0";
});
```

codepen:
https://codepen.io/HBA/pen/BaayQOL