# Text inside slideshow not lining up correctly. See fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any possible way to get the text to not jump up and down? I can't use position: absolute. because it messes up the rest of my website. Please look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/11/

Here is the html:

```
<div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
<div class="rotating-item intro">Text 1</div>
<div class="rotating-item intro">Text 2</div>
<div class="rotating-item intro">Text 3</div>
```

```
<p class="slidermwtext"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p>
```

See fiddle for javascript and css.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the animation supposed to look like?

Comment: just a nice fade in and fade out. No choppiness. I have this working good with images. but as soon as I change to text, it messes up.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/12/)***

Cross-fade is achieved using `position:absolute;` on the fading elements.
So yes, **you need to** set those titles to overlap each-other.

```
#rotating-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height:30px;       /* play with it! */
}
.rotating-item {
    display:none;
    position:absolute; /* needed to X-fade */
    width:100%;        /* needed cause lost due to absolute pos. */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

If you want flexible height of the parent element, sadly you'll need to use javascript (or a library like jQuery) (see: [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height))

Comment: but then how do I make the text centered?

Comment: @kimberlyvoo see the demo and the provided code. (Use 100% width)

Comment: :( Can someone help with that? I can't really write javascript on my own. I just get bits and pieces by searching.

Comment: @kimberlyvoo should the parent animate it's height or should be always equal to the highest child element?

Comment: equal to child element.

Comment: Please help. I can use jQuery but I picked this particular slideshow code because it was small. I don't mind adding some code to what I have but I don't want to add another framework. I absolutely can't have a fixed height because the font and size of text will be dynamically changing.

Comment: The parent should animate its height. Sorry roko I didn't understand the question before. I do now.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.1/slick.min.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.1/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
    background-color: lightblue;
   }
   #slickslide {
       height: 200px;
       background: lightgray;
     }
     #content {
         margin: auto;
         padding: 20px;
         width: 80%;
     }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="demo"></div>
<div id=content>  
  <div id="slickslide" slick="">
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
    <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut. </p></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript  code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slickslide').slick({
         dots: true,
         infinite: true,
         speed: 300,
         autoplay:true,
         autoplaySpeed: 1000,
         slidesToShow: 1,
         slidesToScroll: 1
     });
 });
```

Comment: I m using javascript library Slick.js