# Height of tabs do not expand with their contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tabs which contain text. When I try to set the height with `height:auto` or `height:100%`, it works only when using `px`. However this prevents the tabs from expanding when the text is long.

this is my css:

```
.tab-section {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 792px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

How do I make the height `auto`?

Comment: what about using `overflow: auto;` and add, for example `max-height: 500px;`?

Comment: Use `min-height: 792px`

Comment: "  
what about using overflow: auto; and add, for example max-height: 500px;?   "i have already tried this , but with this create a scrolling in a container with static height , i want the height of page is dynamic when the content change in tabs

Comment: "Use min-height: 792px" not change anithing

Comment: can use css3 in your project?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are displaying the **tab-content** inside the **li** element.
As the **li** it's a menu it looks like a broken layout.

You should display the **tab-content** outside of the **tab-section**.
Also be aware of **floating**(for example, if the parent it has float: left, the child should also have float:left to fulfill the parent height)

Answer (score 0):

`.tab-content` with `position:absolute`

[Based on **feeela** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071017/1476708)

absolute positioned elements are removed from the flow, thus ignored by other elements. So you can't set the parents height according to an absolutely positioned element.

You can use this script to handle it:

```
$("[type = radio]").click(function () {
    var oh=$(this).parent().find(".content").outerHeight();    
    $(".tabs").height(oh);
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nYcR3/14/)

Also you can use viewport units(vh) or calc() on `ul.tabs` (css3)