# How Can I keep my Contact From within my Div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, cross-platform

I have my page created, and at the bottom of the page I have a contact form. However, When I resize the form on inspection, and go to a mobile device, the contact form spills into my footer.

[What I currently have - click here](http://codepen.io/csapty12/pen/WxJmwX)

```
.
```

Could someone show me how this can be fixed? I changed the Z-index of the div I have to keep it within, but it did not make a difference, and nothing else I have tried worked either.

My aim is to keep my contact form proportional cross platform:
Image 1 is what desktop looks like, image 2 is what the issue is:

[image: image1][image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the max-width to `.contact-form>.form-group` so the element's wouldn't overflow

```
.contact-form>.form-group{
  max-width:80%;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work, it still overflows into the footer

Comment: Oh that :) just a second :)

Comment: well there are a couple of problems and you need to change the approach on this, you can't use absolute elements as overlays because that's gonna involve javascript because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height