# parent's relative position grows to fit the child absolute position height

Tags: html, css, height, css-position, blockquote

How can I set the height of a parent (`relative` position) to height of the it's children?

Take a look at [this pen](http://codepen.io/hemedani/pen/vyNXJL) to see it in action.

```css
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #edf0f9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
blockquote img {
  width: 5.5rem;
  height: 5.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
blockquote .name-block {
  padding: 0.1rem 2rem 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  background-color: #6e7480;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
blockquote .pos-block {
  padding: 0.1rem 3rem 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  background-color: #6e7480;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.6rem;
  right: 4rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
blockquote .txt-block {
  background-color: #2b2d32;
  padding: 5rem 1rem 1rem 1.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 0;
}
blockquote .txt-block:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 4.5rem;
  border-left: 2px solid #6e7480;
  height: calc(100% - 5rem);
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <img src="http://7108-presscdn-0-78.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/person-to-person-business.jpg" />
  <span class="name-block">John Doe</span>
  <span class="pos-block">A mannager</span>
  <div class="txt-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate iste ipsam facere reprehenderit iure odio voluptatem quod voluptatibus natus officiis. Consequatur eius architecto deleniti beatae sapiente laboriosam tempora, deserunt officia asperiores
    incidunt ea accusantium debitis blanditiis nesciunt ex minus ipsam nobis unde in distinctio, vero alias magni dolorum dolore? Debitis non aspernatur quis minus laboriosam. Voluptates maxime consequatur doloremque accusantium esse aperiam, voluptate
    voluptas officiis perspiciatis, minus sed ab voluptatum nisi cumque sapiente illo culpa a magnam ducimus omnis animi cum dignissimos? Vero quaerat quisquam ipsam libero porro nulla fugit repellat, accusantium, quidem, laudantium perspiciatis cupiditate
    vel dolore aliquid sapiente rem dolorem voluptatem architecto minus facilis eos expedita alias nesciunt dolores. Eum eos architecto, eveniet illo, sit doloribus, debitis possimus non placeat quibusdam odio quidem ab dicta dolorum blanditiis accusamus.
    Perferendis veniam officiis rem, ex iusto nesciunt! Sit incidunt saepe ab velit, adipisci totam rerum nostrum fugit, architecto deserunt ea!
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

I set the `blockquote` element position to `relative` and set the child of its to `absolute` and when the the `overflow` of the parent set to `hidden` the height of `blockquote` automatically set to 0 and the content just show when `overflow: visible` or height strictly set.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? I don't think it's clear what you're trying to achieve. At least to me it isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height

Comment: you wants this ? https://jsfiddle.net/rfv5hdos/

Comment: I just want the blockquote grows when the `.txt-block` div content is bigger

Comment: So this https://jsfiddle.net/rfv5hdos/ is what you wants

Comment: you just remove absolute position from the `.txt-block` what can do with absolute position in that element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you position an element `absolute`, it is taken out of the *normal flow* and so `blockquote` (which is your parent `relative` element) will have zero height.

Now if if you use `overflow: hidden` on `blockquote`, it will hide everything.

So the best option is to put something on the *normal flow* and that would be `txt-block` - remove `absolute` positioning and give a `margin-top` to get the desired effect - see demo below:

```css
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #edf0f9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
blockquote img {
  width: 5.5rem;
  height: 5.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
blockquote .name-block {
  padding: 0.1rem 2rem 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  background-color: #6e7480;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
blockquote .pos-block {
  padding: 0.1rem 3rem 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  background-color: #6e7480;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.6rem;
  right: 4rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
blockquote .txt-block {
  background-color: #2b2d32;
  padding: 5rem 1rem 1rem 1.8rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}
blockquote .txt-block:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 4.5rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #6e7480;
  height: calc(100% - 5rem);
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <img src="http://7108-presscdn-0-78.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/person-to-person-business.jpg" />
  <span class="name-block">John Doe</span>
  <span class="pos-block">A mannager</span>
  <div class="txt-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate iste ipsam facere reprehenderit iure odio voluptatem quod voluptatibus natus officiis. Consequatur eius architecto deleniti beatae sapiente laboriosam tempora, deserunt officia asperiores
    incidunt ea accusantium debitis blanditiis nesciunt ex minus ipsam nobis unde in distinctio, vero alias magni dolorum dolore? Debitis non aspernatur quis minus laboriosam. Voluptates maxime consequatur doloremque accusantium esse aperiam, voluptate
    voluptas officiis perspiciatis, minus sed ab voluptatum nisi cumque sapiente illo culpa a magnam ducimus omnis animi cum dignissimos? Vero quaerat quisquam ipsam libero porro nulla fugit repellat, accusantium, quidem, laudantium perspiciatis cupiditate
    vel dolore aliquid sapiente rem dolorem voluptatem architecto minus facilis eos expedita alias nesciunt dolores. Eum eos architecto, eveniet illo, sit doloribus, debitis possimus non placeat quibusdam odio quidem ab dicta dolorum blanditiis accusamus.
    Perferendis veniam officiis rem, ex iusto nesciunt! Sit incidunt saepe ab velit, adipisci totam rerum nostrum fugit, architecto deserunt ea!
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

Let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the min-height or height.

```
blockquote {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #edf0f9;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/hemedani/pen/vyNXJL