# CSS side-by-side slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an animated slider so that the "non-active" slides are still shown on the sides.
The height of the children is not known. Also, when resizing the page, the height might increase.
Currently I have this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odoYPx

HTML:

```
<div class="row side-by-side-slider">
  <div class="col-md-6 ss-slide-left ss-slide">
    <div class="ss-slide-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 ss-slide active">
    <div class="ss-slide-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-10 ss-slide">
    <div class="ss-slide-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.side-by-side-slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.side-by-side-slider .ss-slide {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .26;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background: #f5f4f4;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #F5F4F4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 0 #F5F4F4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 45px 70px;
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.side-by-side-slider .ss-slide-left {
    left: -33.3333333%;
}

.side-by-side-slider .ss-slide.active {
    left: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
}
```

The problem is that the parent (.side-by-side-slider) doesn't wrap around the children. I couldn't figure out how to do it without children being "position: absolute" since then I had alignment issues. I left out the slider JS code because for this problem it's not necessary. It's still a work in progress.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the size of the children is known, then you can directly give it as the height for the parent also.

Comment: The height of the children is not known. Also, when resizing the page, the height might increase. The children contain text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just wondering if there was a pure CSS solution, but couldn't make one.
I ended up using jQuery to achieve this. More specifically this function:

```
makeChildHeight() {
  let maxHeight = $('.side-by-side-slider .ss-slide').innerHeight() + 80;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call($('.side-by-side-slider .ss-slide'), function(slide) {
    if ($(slide).innerHeight() + 80 > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(slide).innerHeight() + 80;
    }
  });
  $('.side-by-side-slider').css(
      {'height': maxHeight}
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`https://codepen.io/7ssan91/pen/RyjVNW` you can use this slider with only Html and Css if you want to control of the height you should use media query `https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp`

Comment: Hasan. Post your code directly into SO. SO now support rendering `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` snippet in your answer. Check the top bar of your answer page .