# How do I increase parent element as child element is increased?

Tags: javascript, css

I have two classes and I need to make their the elements same height. As the children element's height is increased, the parent element also needs its height to be increased.

Parent element class is `.user-data` and children element class is `.scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer`.

```
.user-data {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    background-color: white;
}

.scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
 }
```

Parent and children element need to have same class and I also cannot change the `position` property in `.user-data` and `.scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer` due to code not shown here.

Can someone help?

Comment: does the child have to be position: absolute?

Comment: Yes, it has to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height#12071017), you cannot set the parent's height according to an absolute positioned element unless you use fixed height or JavaScript.

---

With JavaScript, you just need to retrieve the height of your absolute positioned child element `.scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer` then set that retrieve value as the height for your `relative positioned` parent element `.user-data`.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I described above. In the following snippet, I changed the parent element's height to be `5px` more than it's `absolute positioned` child element so that you can see the extra height of the parent element:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var child = document.querySelector(".scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer");
var parent = document.querySelector(".user-data");

parent.style.height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(child).height) + 5 + "px";
```

```css
/* CSS */

.user-data {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
}

.scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
 }
 html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="user-data">
  <div class="scheduleWorkingPeriodContainer"><p>ABCD</p><p>ABCD</p><p>ABCD</p><p>ABCD</p>
  </div>
</div>
```