# Absolute position makes parent div missing

Tags: css

I'm trying to study and understand the positions `absolute` and `relative`.

Scenario 1 (relative):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
 
 #container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
 }

 #box1 {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  <div id="box1">
   
   <h1>This is box 1</h1>

  </div>

 </div>
```

I can completely understand the above. When given a relative positioning, its moving 20px from the left of its normal position. So what I studied in theory did make sense and this is clear.

Now, when I tried this - Scenario 2 (absolute):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
 
 #container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
 }

 #box1 {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  <div id="box1">
   
   <h1>This is box 1</h1>

  </div>

 </div>
```

**Question:** Why is that the black background is gone? From what I understood, `box1` should move 20px to its left from its parent (which is currently the browser as I've used absolute for its position).

So it does move, but why is the black background (which was set in its parent) missing? Issn't Box1 nested into it? Why does it go missing?

I've tried googling but I'm unable to understand this logic and would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

[Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height)

I tried to look at this, however, once again I'm not understanding the correct answer.

Comment: When you set position: absolute; you take that element out of the document flow, so for the parent it looks like there's nothing inside it, so it collapses to 0 height, here's a good read about positioning: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: Ah, I see. So I have to manually set a height for the parent div to match the child div with the absolute position? Is that how its done?

Comment: Correct. This is why position: absolute; is used for very specific cases, otherwise it breaks the layout most of the time

Comment: That is awesome, thank you. Yes I tried to manually set a height and it works. And yes I agree, I shall not be using this unless really needed. It does indeed breaks the layout of the website. If you could post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer! Thanks buddy.

Comment: I was out for lunch but no worries for the answer, I'm just glad I helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.container` element is not being “held open” by its absolutely positioned child, so it is collapsing (to 0 height). You can test this by shimming the parent open by defining a `height` in the corresponding CSS.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px; /* for example */
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px; /* for example */
}

#box1 {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="box1">

    <h1>This is box 1</h1>

  </div>

</div>
```

*Unsolicited Advice:* When I am trying to pin down a puzzling effect of a CSS rule, it is helpful to assign the element in question a `border` value. I find this helps reveal the underlying structural effects of my style rules. For example, a border on `.container` reveals that it *is* still there; if impossibly short.

```
#container {
  border: 2px solid lime; /* it helps if it doesn't blend in with your existing page palette, too */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid lime; /* for example */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#box1 {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="box1">

    <h1>This is box 1</h1>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As absolute positioned element doesn't take its space and sets around the relative element.
 So in your structure, you need to give height or some padding to `"#container`".

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set height of `#container`, because `position: absolute` take your `<div id="box1">`  out from the `<div id="container">`  cause `position` is `static` of `#container` by default. For the DOM it looks like `<div id="container">` has nothing and there is nothing rendered:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Please, see difference between `position:static`:

```
.parent {
    border: 2px solid #0074d9;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: #0074d9;
    padding: 5px;
    position: static;
    height: 100px;

  }

  .element {
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 25px;
  }
```

and  `position: relative;`:

```
.parent {
    border: 2px solid #0074d9;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: #0074d9;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;

  }

  .element {
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 25px;
  }
```

In `position:relative` our child container will be placed inside parent element. [Please, read this great article about `position:absolute`.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)