# Getting entire DOM wrapping bounding client rect

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bounding-box

I'm looking for a way to obtain a virtual bounding box that will wrap inside all the DOM elements.

For example, 2 divs with `100X100 px` dimensions with `position absolute` one is placed at `top:0 left :0` and the other is placed at `top:700px left:700px` will result a `800X800` rect (image 1):

[image]

When scrolled I expect to still get an `800X800` rectangular with an offset of the scrolled distance (image 2):
[image]

I'm thinking of iterating through the DOM, getting all bounding client rectangulars and calculate manually, something like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((el)=>{
  let r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  //calculate
})
```

However, it seems not very efficient. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
This is the code so far, any insights would be appreciated:

```
function getDocumentVisualBoundingBox() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"), (res, el) => {
    //Looking at BODY element, Absolute positioned elements and ignoring elements within scrollable containers.
      if (el.tagName === 'BODY' || (el.parentElement && getComputedStyle(el.parentElement).overflow === 'visible' && getComputedStyle(el).position === 'absolute')) {
        let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        res.offsetLeft = Math.min(res.offsetLeft, rect.left);
        res.offsetTop = Math.min(res.offsetTop, rect.top);
        res.width = Math.max(res.width, rect.width + Math.abs(res.offsetLeft) + rect.left);
        res.height = Math.max(res.height, rect.height + Math.abs(res.offsetTop) + rect.top);
      }
      return res;
    }, {
      offsetLeft: 0,
      offsetTop: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up writing my own method:

```
function getDocumentVisualBoundingBox() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"), (res, el) => {
    //Looking at BODY element, Absolute positioned elements and ignoring elements within scrollable containers.
      if (el.tagName === 'BODY' || (el.parentElement && getComputedStyle(el.parentElement).overflow === 'visible' && getComputedStyle(el).position === 'absolute')) {
        let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        res.offsetLeft = Math.min(res.offsetLeft, rect.left);
        res.offsetTop = Math.min(res.offsetTop, rect.top);
        res.width = Math.max(res.width, rect.width + Math.abs(res.offsetLeft) + rect.left);
        res.height = Math.max(res.height, rect.height + Math.abs(res.offsetTop) + rect.top);
      }
      return res;
    }, {
      offsetLeft: 0,
      offsetTop: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with absolute positioned elements, that's impossible, as they are removed from the DOM flow, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height).

You need to do that manually, exactly as you say.

I created a small fiddle to play with this (click elements to change children postion to relative to see how container expands):

```js
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.classList.add("cont");

var a = document.createElement("div")
a.classList.add("abs");

var b = document.createElement("div")
b.classList.add("abs");
b.style.left = b.style.top = "100px";

container.appendChild(a);
container.appendChild(b);
document.body.appendChild(container);

document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
    a.style.position = b.style.position = a.style.position ? "" : "relative";
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.cont {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    background-color: blue;
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```