# Why is <style> tag not working in this code?

Tags: html, css

So  tag never seemed to like me a lot. It always caused me problems, but it was always turning out that their solution was obvious and I was just stupid. But this time, I am spending 4TH HOUR trying to figure out what could've gone wrong (this is exactly why I even named a body content div "body", IK this is unnecessary lol). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--© Copyright LightVoid Studio-->
<html style="font-family: Helvetica, Cursive; color:white;">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LightVoid Studio</title>
</head>

<style>
    .body {
    background-color:#1A2B30;
    }
    </style>
<!--break-->

<body>
<div class="body">
<strong>
<p style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:20px;font-size:40px;">Hello</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:140px;left:20px;">This is the official LightVoid Studio
website. If You're here for the first time, let's tell Ya what We're exactly doing. LightVoid
Studio is a relatively fresh Indie game studio that develops various software, such as games for Your computer.</p>

</div>
</body>


<!--break-->

</html>`
```

Comment: put styles in the <head>  also, it may be working but your p tags being absolute position will essentially pull them out of the div.body   remove the absolute position of the p elements and see if the background color is working on the div.  otherwise add a position:relative to the .body class so the children are relative to it.

Comment: When in doubt, use an HTML validator. Browsers are designed to fix invalid HTML, but they won't necessarily do it the way you'd like.

Comment: `<style>` tags can be placed anywhere in your code. the problem is you're displaying the entire contents of the `.body` class as absolute, so its height will be 0. If you use inspect element, you should be able to see that the `background-color` style is already being applied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height)

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `<div class="body">` has a height of `0`. It only contains absolute positioned elements, which don't take up any space, so its basically empty.

Some suggestions:

1. Learn to use the browser's debugger (DOM Inspector). It will show you information about the elements such as their size and applied styles.
2. Avoid absolute positioning. It basically breaks how CSS works which makes it difficult for beginners.

EDIT: One more thing: You have a opening `<strong>` tag without a closing `</strong>`. Keep in mind  you can't put block elements (such as `<p>`) inside inline elements such as `<strong>`.

Answer (score 1):

I found your mistake.

Navigate to html tag, there you can see the style attribute, with color=white.
This is making all the text white, which is same as canvas therefore it is invisible.

Now, the text tags are absolutely positioned, meaning they are outside the flow, so the height and width of the DIV is 0, so you cannot see any color because the div is essentially a 0x0 box.

I have adjusted the changes, please check:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--© Copyright LightVoid Studio-->
<html style="font-family: Helvetica, Cursive;">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LightVoid Studio</title>
</head>

<style>
    .body {
    background-color:#1A2B30;
    }
    </style>
<!--break-->

<body>
<div class="body">
<strong>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>This is the official LightVoid Studio
website. If You're here for the first time, let's tell Ya what We're exactly doing. LightVoid
Studio is a relatively fresh Indie game studio that develops various software, such as games for Your computer.</p>
</strong>
</div>
</body>


<!--break-->

</html>`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's about where `<style>` is.

But it's your children (elements) are `postition: absolute;` so `.body` is **0 height**.

Try:

```
<div class="body" style="height:100px">
```

So you I will see the problem

(This is just testing, please look at RoToRa's answer)

Comment: Don't teach beginners to hard code things like heights.

Comment: Well, thanks, that fixed my problem. And I am not a beginner, I actually did things like this on my previous websites, but now it seems like it worked quite differently. Thanks Y'all anyway

Answer (score -1):

Because it's outside of closing `</head>` and opening `<body>`

It supposed to be between `<head>` and `</head>`

Comment: Style can be anywhere

Comment: While that is true, it's not the reason it doesn't work.