# Return value from child component to parent component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to use a react Timer in one of my class components. I figured out how to connect it, but now I need to save the time into the parent's state. How can I go upon doing that? Since the time is being measured on the child component. So essentially I need to save the time measured from the child component to the parent's state.

Comment: You can use `useState`, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69497555/how-to-set-parent-node-style-in-react/69497832?noredirect=1#comment122839948_69497832 using

Answer (score 3):

The phrase that comes to mind is [Lifting State up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). React has a 'top-down' data flow. So your state needs to be initialised in the parent component and passed down to the child components that need it. e.g. (pseudocode, may not work)

```js
function Parent() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('hello world')

  return (
    <>
      <Child text={text} />
      <OtherChild text={text} setText={setText} />
    </>
  )  
}

function Child({ text }) {
  return <p>{text}</p>
}

function OtherChild({ text, setText }) {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
      value={text} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Almost right, but they're wanting to update Parent state from Child. The input and onChange listener in your code needs to be on the child.

Comment: Good point, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a function that updates the parent's state to the child component via props:

In this particular example, both the child and the parent props have a state hook that keeps track of time - the parent's `updateParentTime` function get's called any time the child's `time` value changes.

*NOTE*: it's probably not necessary to keep state in both places...I was just showing an example.  If the parent needs has state for `time`, you could also just pass that down to the child component

```
const Parent = (props) => {
   const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

   const updateParentTime = (t) => {
      setTime(t);
   }
 
  return (
    <Child updateParentTime={updateParentTime}/>
  )
}

const Child = (props) => {
   const {updateParentTime} = props;
   const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

   useEffect(() => {
      updateParentTime(time)
   }, [time]);

   return (
     <div>
       {/* something goes here */}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following defines two React components: `Parent` and `Child`.

`Parent` declares a piece of state named `time` and a mutator method for that state named `setTime`.

The current value of `time` is passed to `Child` via the prop named `time`.

`setTime` is passed to `Child` via the prop named `notify`.

`Child` configures a timer that invokes `notify` (ie `setTime`) once a second.

Invoking `notify` tells React that a state change has occurred and triggers a re-rendering of both components, causing the time to be rendered by each component, once every second.

```css
pre { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const Parent = () => {
  const [ time, setTime ] = React.useState('--- --- -- ----')
  return <pre>
           Parent: { time }
           <Child notify={setTime} time={ time }/>
         </pre>
}

const Child = ({ notify, time }) => {    
    useEffect(()=>{
      const id = setInterval(() => notify(Date()), 1000)
      return () => clearInterval(id)      
    })

    return <pre>Child: {time}</pre>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.querySelector('main'))
</script>
<main></main>
```