# Change the height dynamically of an absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code pen below as you can see, when I click the button at the top and append a child to the div, the child being appended leaves its parent element. Is there a way to keep it inside of its parent element WHILE STILL keeping the drag and drop functionality in tact?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Michael-Horvilleur/pen/gOyrVNQ)

```
     <div class="grid">
            <div class="item h2 w2 ">
                <div class="item-content">
                   <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-id"></div> 
                     <h1>yo</h1>
                     <div class="card-remove"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item h1 w2 ">
                <div class="item-content">
                   <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-id"></div> 
                     <div class="height-change-container">
                      <h1>yo</h1>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-remove"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item h2 w1 ">
                <div class="item-content">
                   <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-id"></div> 
                     <h1>yo</h1>
                     <div class="card-remove"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item h1 w3">
                <div class="item-content">
                   <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-id"></div> 
                     <h1>yo</h1>
                     <div class="card-remove"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
              <div class="item h1 w1 ">
                <div class="item-content">
                   <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-id"></div> 
                     <h1>yo</h1>
                     <div class="card-remove"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: FYI StackOverflow also supports runnable snippets (the `<>` button). Have you searched for your question on StackOverflow? See [Make absolute positioned div expand parent div height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070759/make-absolute-positioned-div-expand-parent-div-height). It seems you should calculate the child heights with JavaScript or use some newer CSS concepts like flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

By adding position: absolute ; In the .height-change-container class, you tell the child elements to be positioned relative to their parent container

```
.height-change-container {
  ......
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
   left:0;
  }
```